# How to update the value of one record based on another record with specific criteria in the same dataframes

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

In python, I have a dataframes table of GDP records like this

```
Quarter    Vaule percentage
2017Q1-Q4  100   18%
2017Q1-Q3  60    20%
2017Q1-Q2  30    15%
2017Q1-Q1  10    10%
2016Q1-Q4  10    28%
2016Q1-Q3  6     50%
2016Q1-Q2  3     45%
2016Q1-Q1  1     20%
```

I want the output like this:

```
Quarter    Vaule percentage
2017Q4     40    18%
2017Q3     30    20%
2017Q2     20    15%
2017Q1     10    10%
2016Q4     4     28%
2016Q3     3     50%
2016Q2     2     45%
2016Q1     1     20%
```

That is, the value will be updated based on the computing of other records but the percentage keeps unchanged.

Are there efficient way to deal with this case. Thanks!

Comment: How would the value be calculated, and what have you tried?

Comment: value(2017Q4) = value(2017Q1-Q4) - value(2017Q1-Q3) ,value(2017Q3) = value(2017Q1-Q3) - value(2017Q1-Q2),value(2017Q1-Q2) = value(2017Q1-Q2) - value(2017Q1). value(2017Q1) = value(2017Q1-Q1)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
In [20]: df.loc[~df.Quarter.str.contains(r'\d+Q1-Q1'), 'Vaule'] = df.Vaule.diff(-1)

In [21]: df
Out[21]:
     Quarter  Vaule percentage
0  2017Q1-Q4   40.0        18%
1  2017Q1-Q3   30.0        20%
2  2017Q1-Q2   20.0        15%
3  2017Q1-Q1   10.0        10%
4  2016Q1-Q4    4.0        28%
5  2016Q1-Q3    3.0        50%
6  2016Q1-Q2    2.0        45%
7  2016Q1-Q1    1.0        20%
```

if you also need to change the quarter:

```
In [22]: df.Quarter = df.Quarter.str.split('-').str[0]

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
  Quarter  Vaule percentage
0  2017Q4   40.0        18%
1  2017Q3   30.0        20%
2  2017Q2   20.0        15%
3  2017Q1   10.0        10%
4  2016Q4    4.0        28%
5  2016Q3    3.0        50%
6  2016Q2    2.0        45%
7  2016Q1    1.0        20%
```

Comment: Thanks, other values are correct, but for Q1 it is not correct as the value need to remains the same. For example. Vaule( 2017Q1-Q1) = 10 but not 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.iloc[:-1, 1] = df['Vaule'].diff(-1)[:-1]
>>> df
     Quarter  Vaule percentage
0  2017Q1-Q4     40        18%
1  2017Q1-Q3     30        20%
2  2017Q1-Q2     20        15%
3  2017Q1-Q1      0        10%
4  2016Q1-Q4      4        28%
5  2016Q1-Q3      3        50%
6  2016Q1-Q2      2        45%
7  2016Q1-Q1      1        20%
```

Comment: Thanks, other values are correct, but for Q1 it is not correct as the value need to remains the same. For example. Vaule( 2017Q1-Q1) = 10 but not 0.

Comment: @Harry Not sure I understand.  2017-Q1 = 10.  To which `Q1` are you subsequently referring in `2017Q1-Q1`?  Wouldn't the value be itself, and hence the difference would be zero?

Comment: Not the diffierence for Q1, the initial value is sum value, so  2017-Q1 = 2017Q1-Q1, different with Q2/3/4.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need this:

```
import numpy as np 
df.loc[np.invert(df.Quarter.str.contains('Q1-Q1')), "Vaule"] = df["Vaule"] - df["Vaule"].shift(-1)
df.Quarter = df.Quarter.str.replace('Q1-','')
```

#### A reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from StringIO import StringIO

data = """
Quarter    Vaule percentage
2017Q1-Q4  100   18%
2017Q1-Q3  60    20%
2017Q1-Q2  30    15%
2017Q1-Q1  10    10%
2016Q1-Q4  10    28%
2016Q1-Q3  6     50%
2016Q1-Q2  3     45%
2016Q1-Q1  1     20%
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s+")
df.loc[np.invert(df.Quarter.str.contains('Q1-Q1')), "Vaule"] = df["Vaule"] - df["Vaule"].shift(-1)
df.Quarter = df.Quarter.str.replace('Q1-','')

print(df)
```

output:

```
  Quarter  Vaule percentage
0  2017Q4   40.0        18%
1  2017Q3   30.0        20%
2  2017Q2   20.0        15%
3  2017Q1   10.0        10%
4  2016Q4    4.0        28%
5  2016Q3    3.0        50%
6  2016Q2    2.0        45%
7  2016Q1    1.0        20%
```

PS: @MaxU solution `df.Vaule = df.Vaule.diff(-1)` is more concise. With that in mind, the code would look like this:

```
import numpy as np 
df.loc[np.invert(df.Quarter.str.contains('Q1-Q1')), "Vaule"] = df.Vaule.diff(-1)
df.Quarter = df.Quarter.str.replace('Q1-','')
```

Comment: Thanks, other values are correct, but for Q1 it is not correct as the value need to remains the same. For example. Vaule( 2017Q1-Q1) = 10 but not 0.